# my loop only works for the last file R

Tags: r, loops

Only the last file in the list of text files produces a pdf.
Not sure why?

```
files <- (Sys.glob("/users/local/Documents/*segmentCN.txt"))

for (i in length(files)) {

    y <- read.table(files[i], header=TRUE)

    cn1m0 <- subset(y, subset=(mCn == 0 & Cn == 1), select = c("log2", "imba"))

    pdf(file = paste(files[i], ".pdf", sep=""))
    plot(cn1m0$log2, cn1m0$imba, col=128, xlim=c(-1, 1), ylim=c(0,1))
    points(mean(cn1m0$log2), mean(cn1m0$imba), pch = 3, col="red")

    dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `length(files)` outputs the length of the list, so you're taking only the last file.

Try

```
for (i in 1:length(files))
```

Or the more safe:

```
for (i in seq(along = files))
```