# Creating a master data frame

Tags: r

I am having a problem creating a master data frame from a list of files, when I load it all it gives me is the last id number not the rest, help?

```
    options(max.print=10000000)
    pollutant<-function(id)
     {
     for (i in 1:id){
     filenames = sprintf("%03d.csv", i)
      masterframe<-read.csv(filenames)
     }
     realdata<-na.omit(masterframe)
      realdata
      }
```

---

I try to make a master data frame of data files up to id and use this code

```
              options(max.print=10000000)
               pollutant<-function(id,pollutant){
               for (i in 1:id) {
                filenames=list.files(pattern="csv")
               df.list = lapply(filenames, function(i) na.omit(read.csv(i)))
               master.df = do.call(rbind, df.list)}
               master.df}
```

but I keep getting a master data frame for all 332 files , it doesn't limit itself to id when I run it
any ideas?

Comment: `filenames=list.files(pattern="csv"); df.list = lapply(filenames, read.csv); master.df = do.call(rbind, df.list)`

Comment: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715143/the-for-loop-in-r-returns-only-the-last-iteration) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584177/why-for-loop-only-shows-result-of-last-loop) [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114140/my-loop-only-works-for-the-last-file-r) [four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516298/r-nested-loop-returning-only-the-last-iteration)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the links posted by @rawr, you're overwriting `masterframe` each time through the loop, so `realdata` is just the last file imported. It looks like you want something more like this:

```
realdata = list()

for (i in 1:id) {
  filenames = sprintf("%03d.csv", i)
  masterframe <- read.csv(filenames)
  realdata[[filenames]] = na.omit(masterframe)
}
```

However, `lapply` is probably a cleaner approach:

```
# Get vector of filenames to read
filenames=list.files(pattern="csv")

# Read all the files into a list of data frames
df.list = lapply(filenames, function(x) na.omit(read.csv(x)))

# Combine into a single data frame
master.df = do.call(rbind, df.list)
```